# How to add custom tab in product details page in magento 2.4.0

Tags: blocks, custom, tabs, product-detail-page, magento2.4.0

how to add a new custom tab in the product detail page in magento2

> Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes"
               name="product.custom-info.tab"
               as="custom-info.tab" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/custom.phtml" group="detailed_info">
            <arguments>
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">CUSTOM TAB</argument>
                <argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">20</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
  </body>
</page>
```

> Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/custom.phtml

```
<?php
echo $this->getLayout()
->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')
->setBlockId('custom-info')
->toHtml();
?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You might like this one below: this will work using one layout only `catalog_product_view.xml`, no need of template

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text\ListText" name="product.custom-info.tab" as="custom-info.tab" group="detailed_info">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">CUSTOM TAB</argument>
                    <argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">10</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>

        <referenceBlock name="product.custom-info.tab">
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="block_tab_product_details">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">custom-info</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

can you replace below code with your xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View"
               name="product.custom-info.tab"
               as="custom-info.tab" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/custom.phtml" group="detailed_info">
            <arguments>
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">CUSTOM TAB</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
  </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to your **`catalog_product_view.xml`** file and add below code :-

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View"
               name="product.custom-info.tab"
               as="custom-info.tab" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/custom.phtml" group="detailed_info">
            <arguments>
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Your Tab Name</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
```

After your Create new file in **`Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/custom.phtml`**

```
<?php
echo $this->getLayout()
->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')
->setBlockId('custom-info')
->toHtml();
?>
```

And Run :-

```
php bin/magento c:c
php bin/magento c:f
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For Magento >= 2.4.5 you must change the product layout, form "Product — Full Width" to "No Layout Updates"

Magento product tabs do not work on the frontend on version >= 2.4.5 with layout "Product — Full Width" so you want be enable to see your new tab if you do not change the design layout.

Comment: Are you sure this answer is related to this question ? If yes, can you elaborate a bit more ?